# Does GCC .bss section occupy memory space in the condition that An embedded system without flash who's LMA and VMA are both in RAM ?

Tags: gcc, memory, linker-scripts

I am implementing GCC linker script on an embedded system without flash,which has RAM ONLY.

```
 MEMORY {
       RAM(rwx)  :ORIGIN = 0x04000000, LENGTH = 160K
       DLM(rwx)  :ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS 
{
   .text :
       {
        *(.text*)
      }>RAM AT>RAM
     .data :
       {
        *(.data*)
      }>RAM AT>RAM
     .bss :
       {
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
      }>RAM AT>RAM

}
```

the result is that .bss section OCCUPIES the RAM memory size on LMA view, which is not reasonable. the .bss should not occupy RAM size on LMA view,and would occupy VMA memory size when system runs the .bss region init

BUT when I modify as below

```
 .bss :
   {
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
  }>DLM AT>RAM
```

the result is that .bss section DOES NOT occupy size on LMA view which is expected according to GCC ld.

but why .bss section occupies RAM memory size when the LMA and VMA are both in the same memory(RAM)? it does not make sense.